# OpenMP behavior - Nested Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

My question pertains to nested parallelism and OpenMP. Let's start with the following single threaded code snippet:

```
void performAnotherTask() {
    // DO something here
}

void performTask() {
    // Do other stuff here
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performAnotherTask();
    }
}


int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performTask();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Now let's say we want to make our calls to `performAnotherTask` in parallel utilizing OpenMP.

So we get the following code:

```
void performAnotherTask() {
    // DO something here
}

void performTask() {
    // Do other stuff here
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performAnotherTask();
    }
}


int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performTask();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that the calls to `performAnotherTask` will be performed in parallel, and by default openMP will try and use all available threads on your machine (perhaps this assumption is incorrect).

Let's say we now also want to parallelize the calls to `performTask` such that we get the following code:

```
void performAnotherTask() {
    // DO something here
}

void performTask() {
    // Do other stuff here
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performAnotherTask();
    }
}


int main() {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performTask();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

How will this work? Will both the for loops still be multithreaded? Can we say anything on the number of threads each loop will use? Is there a way to enforce the inner for loop (within `performTask`) to only utilize a single thread while the outer for loop uses all available threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your last example, the execution behavior depends on a few environmental settings.

First, OpenMP indeed does support such patterns, but by default disables parallel execution in a nested parallel region.  To enabled it, you must set `OMP_NESTED=true` or call `omp_set_nested(1)` in your code.  Then the support for nested parallel execution is enabled.

```
void performAnotherTask() {
    // DO something here
}

void performTask() {
    // Do other stuff here
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performAnotherTask();
    }
}


int main() {
    omp_set_nested(1);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performTask();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Second, when OpenMP reaches the outer `parallel` region, it might grab all the available cores and assume that it can execute a thread on them, so you might want to reduce the number of threads for the outer level, so that some cores are available for in nested region.  Say, if you have 32 cores, you could do this:

```
void performAnotherTask() {
    // DO something here
}

void performTask() {
    // Do other stuff here
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performAnotherTask();
    }
}


int main() {
    omp_set_nested(1);
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performTask();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

The outer parallel region will execute using 4 threads, each of which will execute the inner region with 8 threads.  Note, each of the 4 outer threads will be one of the master threads of the four concurrently executing nested parallel regions.  If you want to be more flexible, you can inject the number of threads to use for each level using the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.  If you set it to `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4,8` you get the same behavior as the above the first code snippet that I have posted.

The problem with the coding pattern is that you need to be careful in balancing each level to not overload the system or get load imbalances between the nested parallel regions.  An alternative solution is to use OpenMP tasks instead:

```
void performAnotherTask() {
    // DO something here
}

void performTask() {
    // Do other stuff here
#pragma omp taskloop
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performAnotherTask();
    }
}


int main() {
    omp_set_nested(1);
#pragma omp parallel 
#pragma omp single
#pragma omp taskloop
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        performTask();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Here each of the `taskloop` constructs will generate OpenMP task that are scheduled to execute on the threads that have been created by the single `parallel` region in the code. Caveate is that tasks are inherently dynamic in their behavior, so you might lose locality properties as you do not know where exactly the tasks will be executing in the system.